# Building a tweet bot in C# using TweetSharp error

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a tweet bot in a C# console application using the TweetSharp nugget package. Below is my code:

```
    private static TwitterService service = new TwitterService(apikey, apisercetkey, accesstoken, accesstokensecert);    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"<{DateTime.Now}> - Bot Started");
        SendTweet("For the worst thing that could possibly happen, this is actually going extremely well.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void SendTweet(string _status)
    {
        service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { Status = _status }, (tweet, response) =>
         {
             if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
             {
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                 Console.WriteLine($"<{DateTime.Now}> - Tweet Sent!");
                 Console.ResetColor();

             }
             else
             {
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                 Console.WriteLine($"Tweet Failed" + response.Error.Message);
                 Console.ResetColor();

             }

         });

    }
```

When it compiles I get the below:

[image: Console Error]

I have used the debugger, It is getting to the Send tweet function and falling over there. When it tries to set the Status it fails and jumps to the end of the bracket:

```
service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { Status = _status }, (tweet, response) =>
```

I have tried remaking the program as I through it might be that TweetSharp was buggy with my Framework version. I was using .net framework 4.7.2. Have tried it on 4.7, 4.6.1 also and same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What point in the debugger is it getting to?

Comment: comment out your `service` class field, and everything else but the `Console.WriteLine`s in Main.  Then run your program. If it runs correctly, uncomment things till you reproduce the error.  Based on the code (I have no knowledge of the TwitterService library), it looks like the constructor might be causing the error

Comment: Ok will give that a go an then update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that TweetSharp is no longer being maintained as it had a lot of issue with the Twitter API 1.1. I have switched to using TweetSharp-Unoffical version instead, this also seems to be unsupported but it has fixed the problem.